# How to concat a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I am fetching the data from mongoDB to python through pymongo and then converting it into pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.dataset2.find()))
```

This is how data looks like in mongoDB.

```
"dish" : [
      {
        "dish_id"          : "005" ,
        "dish_name"        : "Sandwitch",
        "dish_price"       : 50,
        "coupon_applied"   : "Yes",              
        "coupon_type"      : "Rs 20 off"
      },
      {
        "dish_id"          : "006" ,
        "dish_name"        : "Chicken Hundi",
        "dish_price"       : 125,
        "coupon_applied"   : "No",
        "coupon_type"      : "Null"

      }
   ],
```

I want to seperate dish attributes into two rows in pandas dataframe. Here is the code which does that. (There are 3 dish documents) so, I am iterating it through for loop.

```
for i in range(0,len(df.dish)):
data_dish = json_normalize(df['dish'][i])
print data_dish
```

But it gives me below output..

```
 coupon_applied   coupon_type   dish_id     dish_name       dish_price  
0            Yes   Rs 20 off     001     Chicken Biryani         120   
1             No        Null     001      Paneer Biryani         100   

coupon_applied  coupon_type     dish_id   dish_name        dish_price  
0        Yes       Rs 40 off     002     Mutton Biryani      130   
1        No          Null        004      Aaloo tikki         95   


coupon_applied   coupon_type    dish_id   dish_name        dish_price 
0     Yes         Rs 20 off      005      Sandwitch           50   
1     No             Null        006     Chicken Hundi        125
```

And I want output in following format..

```
  coupon_applied   coupon_type   dish_id     dish_name       dish_price  
0     Yes          Rs 20 off      001     Chicken Biryani      120   
1     No             Null         001      Paneer Biryani      100   
2     Yes          Rs 40 off      002     Mutton Biryani       130   
3     No             Null         004      Aaloo tikki         95   
4     Yes         Rs 20 off       005      Sandwitch           50   
5     No             Null         006     Chicken Hundi        125
```

Can you help me with this? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you just create the `pd.DataFrame()` directly from the mangoDB data?

Comment: Please consider to give us a full sample of the dataframe in order to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is

```
dishes = [json_normalize(d) for d in df['dish']]
df = pd.concat(dishes, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: those are not 3 different data frames its one data frame i.e returned by json_normalize function.

Comment: one more thing.. I want to replicate some rows in dataframe depending upon dish (json array). Dish may contain 3 dishes. When its only one i can do that by following    `def data_shape(dataframe):
    data_dish = json_normalize(dataframe['dish'][0])
    count = len(data_dish)              ## counting dishes ordered 
    new_dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe]*count,ignore_index=True)
    final_dataframe = pd.concat([new_dataframe,data_dish],axis=1)
    print final_dataframe `

Comment: It might be more productive to post a new question for your follow on here, it's a bit tricky to understand in comments. Please let me know if you need any additional info or if you find the above answer acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a list of dataframes in a list and then concat them.

Inizialize a new Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Create an empty list of Dataframes:

```
dflist = []
```

Loop and append dataframes

```
for i in range(0,len(df.dish)):
    data_dish = json_normalize(df['dish'][i])
    dflist.append(data_dish)
```

Then concat the list into the full dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat(dflist, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thnks for your rpl. Its adding an index properly. But the same dataframe is repeating 3 times.

Comment: @user2927983 yep, maybe try to change the index of the loop as reported in the other answer.